# Find the minimum value of the trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

If $x + y = 2c$, find minimum value of 
$ \sec x +\sec y $ if $x,y\in(0,\pi/2)$, in terms of $c$.

I was able to solve by differentiating the equation and got the answer as 2secc.
But i would like to know solution with trigonometry as base or without differentiating the equation.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried differentiating and got the answer but i want solution with pure trigonometry or without differentiating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method without differentiation.

Since $x,y\in(0,\pi/2)$

$\sec x,\sec y>0$

By using $A.M\ge G.M$, we have 
$$\dfrac{\sec x+\sec y}{2}\ge\sqrt{\sec x\cdot\sec y}$$
$$\sec^2x+\sec^2y+2\sec x\sec y\ge4\sec x\sec y$$
$$\sec^2x+\sec^2y-2\sec x\sec y\ge0$$
$$(\sec x-\sec y)^2\ge0$$
$$\sec x-\sec y=0$$
$$x=y$$
Since, $x+y=2c$
$$x+x=2c$$
$$x=c$$
$$\sec x+\sec y=2\sec x\mbox{ which is the minimum}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x) = \sec x$ has $f''(x) = \sec x\tan^2 x + \sec^3 x > 0$ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Thus $f(x)$ is convex on the indicated domain and it follows that $\sec x + \sec y \ge 2\sec\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)= 2\sec c$ which is the minimum value.

Comment: I mentioned that answer should be with trigonometry has base or without differentiation

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sec x+\sec y)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos^2y}\frac{dy}{dx}=0,\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=-1,\\
\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x}=\frac{\sin y}{\cos^2y}\\
\Rightarrow x=y=c.$$
Minimum value: $2\sec c.$

Comment: I mentioned that answer should be with trigonometry has base or without differentiation

Answer (score 0):

$$u=\sec x+\sec y=\dfrac{4\cos\dfrac{x+y}2\cos\dfrac{x-y}2}{\cos(x-y)+\cos(x+y)}$$

$$u=\dfrac{4\cos C\cdot t}{2t^2-1+\cos2c}$$

which is a quadratic equation in $t=\cos\dfrac{x-y}2$

As $t$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

See [Proving ${1+\cos x\over2+\sin x} < \frac43$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242973/proving-1-cos-x-over2-sin-x-frac43/3243092#3243092)